# Installing compiled package from .zip file: copy/paste vs. install.packages

Tags: r

I just downloaded a .zip file off of Rforge. Is there a difference between installing the package with `install.packages("pathtozip",repos = NULL)` and just copying the package folder into the R library?

In the past, when I have updated R, I have just copied over the package folders form older versions of R. I am wondering if I need to go back and do a better job getting all the packages installed properly.

Comment: Why not try it out and see what, if any, differences are in the `.../library/some_package/...` directories?   Or take a look at `install.packages` to see all the options available and what they do.  (Leaving aside the fact that one can only unzip&copy binaries, not source package tarballs)

Comment: I cannot see any difference in the files contained in the folders. And I realize I could not copy/paste the source files. I have yet to figure out how to make that mess work on my Windows computer at work. But if I am just working with binary files - especially when updating R - are there things I need to worry about?